# combine contracts precondition to return error once?

Tags: c#, code-contracts

HI there

I was wondering if there is anyway to combine all Contract.Requiere in a method, so say something like this happens

```
public void MyMehod(Order var1, Cust var2)
{
   Contract.Requires<ArgumentException>(var1 != null);
   Contract.Requires<ArgumentException>(var2 != null);  
   //...
}
```

And that if I call **MyMehtod** and both *var1* and *var2* are null I get both error messages?

(maybe the example is not great) but the idea is that if call the method, I want to know everything that's wrong with it 
So, does anyone know if its possible to combine the Contracts so that I get one error message back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One really crufty way - which doesn't scale to lots of arguments - is to first have a contract which will fail if *both* are null:

```
Contract.Requires<ArgumentException>(var1 != null || var2 != null);
```

or

```
Contract.Requires<ArgumentException>(!(var1 == null && var2 == null));
```

... but then you'd still need the two individual ones. I don't think I'd recommend actually *doing* this, but it's the only thing I can think of offhand.

Comment: Thanks Jon, very fast answer :) . It would be a handy feature